# CATransaction Delay

Tags: iphone, core-animation, catransaction

How can I set the delay of my implicit animation in core animation? I'm surprised that there is no kCATransactionAnimationDelay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't. You need to create explicit CAAnimation objects instead to represent your animations if you need this kind of control over it.

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
// Start in 5 seconds
theAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()+5;
```

CAAnimation objects implement the [CAMediaTiming protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html) so you have a few properties to play around with in there.

(answer taken from [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2008/May/msg00059.html))

Comment: The original poster was talking about implicit animations, not explicit ones.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're doing an implicit animation, would you be better off just using UIView-based animation? It easily allows delays, and unless I'm mistaken, gives you access to exactly the same functionality you find when using implicit Core Animations.

Comment: not true, only a limited number of things are animatable for a uiview and some don't seem to always work right (such as resizing a frame)

Comment: 1) I could be wrong, but we were talking about implicit animations, not explicit...and I think those offer the same functionality as is exposed through UIView. 2) It's (maybe) irrelevant, because iOS 7 has greatly expanded the kinds of animation you can do through UIView.